# How to optimize this loop into one linq query removing the loop call entirely?

Tags: asp.net, linq, query-optimization, jqplot, linq-to-objects

I have this loop that builds these `IEnumerables` one by one, I'd like to be able to optimize this so that it can make the call and build all of these `IEnumerables` at once in one `IEnumerable` instead of a list of them as the loop has to do. The code is grouping FilteredCases (cases of different types of trees in one year) by month and calculating the percentage of trees for that month compared to the whole year. My problem is that I am doing this separately for each year and would like to do this in one LINQ call hopefully by grouping the correct data together.

Here's the code:

```
        var seriesDataLineList = new List<IEnumerable<SeriesDataPointArray>>();

        foreach (var tree in trees)
        {
            IEnumerable<SeriesDataPointArray> seriesDataLine = months.Select(month => new SeriesDataPointArray()
            {
                X = month.LookupMonthName,
                Y = new object[] { Math.Round(FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId && fc.LookupMonthId == month.LookupMonthId) / (double)FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId) * 100, 0) }
            });

            seriesDataLineList.Add(seriesDataLine);
        }
```

My attempt at doing this with LINQ:

```
var test = from fc in FilteredCases
           group fc by new { fc.Tree, fc.Month }
           into casesGrouped
           orderby casesGrouped.Key.Tree
           select new { casesGrouped.Key.Tree, casesGrouped.Key.Month, count = casesGrouped.Count() };
```

But I'm not sure how to get these into one `IEnuerable<SeriesDataPointArray>`

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is a mix of loops and linq, which can get confusing because you are mixing iterative with set based logic. If you expand the code out as just loops, you may find it easier to translate to linq.

As all loops

```
        var seriesDataLineList = new List<SeriesDataPointArray>();
        foreach (var tree in trees)
        {
            foreach (var month in months)
            {
                var seriesDataLine = new SeriesDataPointArray()
                {
                    X = month.LookupMonthName,
                    Y = new double[] { Math.Round(FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId && fc.LookupMonthId == month.LookupMonthId) / (double)FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId) * 100, 0) }
                };
                seriesDataLineList.Add(seriesDataLine);
            };
        }
```

Once you get the code in all loops, converting to linq is fairly straight forward. Nested loops are functionally equivalent a cartesian product, which syntactically in linq can be achieved by multiple uncorrelated for statements.

```
        var results = from tree in trees
                      from month in months
                      select new SeriesDataPointArray()
                      {
                          X = month.LookupMonthName,
                          Y = new double[] { Math.Round(FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId && fc.LookupMonthId == month.LookupMonthId) / (double)FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId) * 100, 0) }
                      };
```

Or in lambda, multiple nested select statements. You'll need a SelectMany() in there somewhere to flatten out the nested collections.

```
        var results = trees.Select(tree =>
            months.Select(month =>
                new SeriesDataPointArray()
                {
                    X = month.LookupMonthName,
                    Y = new double[] { Math.Round(FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId && fc.LookupMonthId == month.LookupMonthId) / (double)FilteredCases.Count(fc => fc.LookupTreeId == tree.LookupTreeId) * 100, 0) }
                }
            )
        ).SelectMany(x => x);
```